# How to re-render component after fetch request and state change?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, fetch

I'm new to react and tying in the back end but after I make the fetch requests, I have to reload the page to see any changes. The database is updated as soon as the functions are called but the component doesn't re-render. I know setState works asynchronously, so I tried calling my functions in the callback of setState but that did not work.

This happens on both my `handleSubmit` and `handleDelete` functions. My initial get request is in my componentDidMount so I'm including that in case it helps.

I couldn't find the answer that I needed on the site, maybe the recommendations were just off but here I am, lol. Thanks in advance.

```js
     componentDidMount() {
          // todos is the data we get back
          // setting the state to newly aquired data
          fetch("/api/todos")`enter code here`
               .then(res => res.json())
               .then(todos => this.setState({ todos }, () => 
               console.log("Todos fetched...", todos)))
               .catch(err => console.log(err))
    
      }
    
    
    // onClick for submit button
        handleSubmit = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const data = this.state;
            fetch("/api/todos", {
                method: "post",
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            })
        };
    
    
    // onClick for delete button
         handleDelete = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            let uniqueId = e.target.getAttribute("id")
            fetch(`/api/todos/${uniqueId}`, {
                method: "delete",
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            })
         };
    
    // Some of the JSX if needed
         <DeleteBtn
             id={todo._id}
             onClick={this.handleDelete}
         >X</DeleteBtn>
    
    <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} id="myForm"></Form>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

The result I'm looking for is once I add a todo, for it to render on my list immediately, rather than only upon page reload.

Comment: Are you sure about class component?
I would suggest to start smoothly moving to functional components and hooks.

Comment: This was a while ago, i use hooks / functional components now

Answer (score 0):

Return the details from the back-end in the requests, use that values to update the state,

Currently you just perform the operation on the back-end and front-end doesn't know that it happened in the back-end. 
The Best way is to either pass the full data(list or object) back to front-end after operation performed on the DB and link the values to a state, 
if the data is bulk then send a success message(200 is enough) back from back-end to front-end and if success change the value(list) in front-end,
Link the value(list) to a state in front-end to have a re rendering of the component.

Answer (score 0):

you've to update your state, and once you'll update the state your component will re-render and it'll shows the latest changes. 
Here i am assuming "todos" you've set in your state is an array, then just update it on deleting and adding. 
i.e:

```
  // onClick for submit button
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const data = this.state;
        const currentTodos = [...this.state.todos]
        fetch("/api/todos", {
            method: "post",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        }).then(()=>{
           currentTodos.push(data);
           this.setState({todos:currentTodos})
        })
    };
 // similarly for delete you can do

 // onClick for delete button
     handleDelete = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let uniqueId = e.target.getAttribute("id")
        let currentTodos = [...this.state.todos];
        fetch(`/api/todos/${uniqueId}`, {
            method: "delete",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        }).then(()=>{
         let updatedTodos = currentTodos.filter(todo=>todo._id !==uniqueId);
         this.setState({todos:updatedTodos})
      })
     };
```

Comment: Hey man this solution is almost working really well. One thing though, once i delete, i guess it returns uniqueId as null? Once I delete everything and add new tasks, and try to delete, i get a 404 thats telling me the fetch is requesting a "/api/todos/null" route, where uniqueId should be in the place of null.

Comment: My mistake, it actually seems to be an issue with the handleSubmit. Looks like data is being sent through as a todos state object rather than an index that would fit correctly in the currentTodos array.  For an example data is returning "1: {todos: Array(1), task: "asdf", from: "asdf"}" .....while it should look like "{_id: "5d77c380e7cc95407482d79a", task: "asdf", from: "asdf", __v: 0}"....Sorry for the longwinded, cluttered response. Seems to me that its just pulling from state rather than interacting with the database,  only just say that bc of the lack of "__v" & "_id".

Comment: So is your problem solved? or does it still exists?

Comment: The problem still exists, it often takes 2 clicks of the buttons for the task to be added or deleted. Inconsistent too, as it only does this like 50% of the time. The database updates correctly each time, its just the front end from what I can see.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not changing your state "todos" that is why it doesn't render. You could fetch todos after every change (after remove, update, add...) or change the state yourself.

Methode 1:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getTodos();
}

getTodos = () => {
    //fetch todos, setState
}

handleSubmit = () => {
    fetch(...).then(this.getTodos);
}

handleDelete = () => {
    fetch(...).then(this.getTodos);
}
```

Methode 2:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getTodos();
}

getTodos = () => {
    //fetch todos, setState
}

handleSubmit = () => {
    fetch(...);
    let todos = this.state.todos;
    todos.push(newTodo);
    this.setState({todos});
}

handleDelete = () => {
    fetch(...);
    let todos = this.state.todos;
    //remove todo from todos
    this.setState({todos});
}
```